# How can MySQL return an empty row matching a given table's schema, given the table name as an input string?

Tags: mysql, query, instance

How can a query or procedure return an empty copy of a new record?

Ideally suited for objects which are in a transactional allocation process:
It is highly preferable to have authoritative defaults and NULLS for arbitrary tables when constructing `new objects()` that *may-or-may not* ultimately be saved to the database.

For example, a CMS user relies on AJAX which calls for a `new post()` or `new product()` dynamically. Rather than trusting stored profiles to set values in the scripting language, a blank "instance" of a row would be rather useful.

Answer (score 0):

From a pure database perspective this isn't really possible, unless you made a [View](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/views.html) that had a single row with the default values you needed that matched the schema of your table.

This question might be better suited on StackOverflow for how to construct a new instance of an entity object in JavaScript or whichever other object-oriented languages you're using.

Comment: While I can understand the desire to offload this to the OOP scripting language; it rather flies in the face of the goal here and answers a different question. If it is possible with a View; would it be workable with a temp table somehow?  Complexity or runtime is not important as we can save the result to existing stored profiles - which data class construction uses on the OOP side - but we need the results of a NULL insert without actually changing the primary key or adding to the dataset

Comment: @GaretClaborn The reason for the suggestion that your question is better off in an OOP forum like StackOverflow is because it's not really a reasonably conceivable question for databases. For comparison it's as reasonable of a request as if I asked how to use only HTML as a database to store all my data. I don't mean this offensively or to be pedantic, but it's literally the wrong tool for the job, and you'll get much better solutions for your end goal asking the question from that perspective. To try to answer your question anyway, yes you can use a TempTable (or global TempTable depending...

Comment: ...on the scope of access needed from your application side (I would guess a global TempTable, more likely). But you run the risk of the Temp database getting cleared out (e.g. on server restart). A physical table that's a copy of your actual table might help you there. There's a number of options that can be shoehorned to accomplish what you're trying to do, I think a `View` is your cleanest bet though. Usually the ORM, micro-ORM, or manually mapped concrete class can be used to define the defaults of an entity object on the application side though, as is normal practice.

Comment: yea, as mentioned the application has been using such a technique for a long time (across many projects.) indeed using an ORM. what im requesting is actually intended for use in the ORM's cache. because so many mappings are involved which can change dynamically there have been some rather nuanced issues. while i have nothing against a View based approach, we really only need it to exist for the duration of a stored procedure which is NOT called every object instantiation but only on the UpdateSchema() command issued from the ORM. I really do get where you are coming from and expected as much..

Comment: .. however if you have any familiarity with RESO Data Dictionaries and the level of consistency across different implementations (or rather the LACK of consistency) you may understand why there are numerous mappings going beyond the ORM's natural capability

Comment: @GaretClaborn Just to make sure I can properly do my homework, is [this](https://ddwiki.reso.org/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=29242439#content/view/29242439) what you're referring to?

Comment: oh pretty close, https://www.reso.org/downloads/ here you can find all the downloads to the actual dictionary versions (starting at the top of the list is a zip file with an XML describing the standard schema and an excel file for the same)

Comment: @GareyClaborn I see, and what object are you trying to model from this data with default values?

Comment: well there's a few hundred different providers of MLS data of which some follow the data dictionary and some do not. some implement up to a certain point, some have totally different column names for the same information, different enums, etc etc etc. so there are many mappings from individual implementations to the RESO standard and from previous dictionary standards to the current version. the ORM produces objects for all of these and there are times where casting from one to the other is non-trivial, especially in cases like different format of same data or different enum values

Comment: any given source could change the definition of their implementation, causing dynamic changes for us upstream of them. there is much less complexity if we are able to query tables for their current representation in natural output than trust the tracking of all the changes and mappings between each other. being able to select an "empty row" that's not simply all NULLs but has the defaults just as the db would set them will allow for a large amount of code reduction and greater reliability of the final solution. allows us not to need a class specialization for each mls

Comment: finally there are some things i am partially locked into; as real estate technology is woefully behind the times. there are system design conventions used by the industry which make little or no rational sense in modern computing but nevertheless are part of compliance

Comment: @GaretClaborn The problem you face is actually not uncommon among other industries, so there's actually a global standard called [**EDI** (**Electronic Data Interchange**)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_data_interchange) that is meant to simplify or solve the problem across all industries (before the database). You should look into that as the most optimal way to solve your problem (though certainly not the easiest upfront, in the long run is the correct solution). Not sure if it's applicable to your business but there are paid providers of EDI services for every industry...

Comment: seems like [this](http://www.fridaysolutions.net/index.php/ediservicesindustries/ediservicesrealestate) might be one, but definitely do your research first (as you'd know the industry better than me). **EDI** is the defacto standard solution to the struggles you've been facing. I've used it for consolidating different related "standards" of data from different large electronic component vendors and even built my own system  that dynamically mapped (like an opposite direction ORM) the different source datasets to a common database schema (my language of choice was C# so this was fairly simple).

Answer (score 0):

Approach it the opposite way -- Your app determines the object definitions.  When the code ultimately decides to save an instance to the database, *then* it constructs an appropriate `INSERT`, *or multiple inserts*, to store the data in one *or more* table(s).

Comment: wellll, appreciate it but alas no. what you describe is already the approach being taken by the app for several years. the question is seeking to approach this purely from the database side due to needs which cannot be met outside the database with the same level of veracity. unfortunately that answers a different question than being asked. I've got close from `SELECT t.* FROM (SELECT NULL) x LEFT JOIN "myTable" t ON false;` but no default values unfortunately. While I can understand you may not like the approach, please consider how to achieve it anyway if remotely possible. thanks

Comment: Side note, as mentioned in another answer -- complexity or runtime is not important as we can save the result to existing stored profiles -- which we could use to then continue doing instantiation through the app as normal and as you are suggesting. As long as the result is something we can poll from time to time in order to update code generators that would be fine. However just looping over all column names and providing in-app defaults is causing some issues with the number of datasource we are normalizing to a standard set of schemas